# How to have Doxygen correctly identify a C++ template partial specialization class symbol and link to its documentation

Tags: c++, templates, documentation, doxygen

I have this code:

```cpp
  template <class V, class E> class bar {}; // primary

  /// @brief Integer specialization 0
  template <> class bar<int, int>  {};

  /// @brief Partial Integer specialization 1
  template <class V> 
  requires(!std::is_same_v<V, int>)
  class bar<V, int>  {};

  /// @brief Partial Integer specialization 2
  template <class E> 
  requires(!std::is_same_v<E, int>)
  class bar<int, E>  {};

  /// @brief Another specialization 3
  template <class V, class E> 
  requires(!std::is_same_v<V, int> && !std::is_same_v<E, int>)
  class bar<V, E>  {};
```

In a page of my documentation I want to refer to these different specializations. However, my naive approach does not work:

```
Please see doc of class: `bar<int,E>`
```

Doxygen generates correctly the documentation pages of every specialization, but it does not recognize symbols properly in the rest of the documentation: for example the symbol `bar<int,E>` links to the empty documentation page of the primary template `bar` instead of linking to specialization 2.

I don't think I can have Doxygen work out the template stuff, so instead how can I have it "artificially" link an inlined block of code like `bar<int,E>` to the desired class documentation ?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? dir you have a look at `\ref` and `\link`, when they don't give the direct result have a look at the possibilities of `\anchor`.

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.5. `\ref` and `\link` do only one part of the job. That is I could write `\link MyClass Some text \endlink`, but again the symbol MyClass is not recognized properly by autolink. I was actually looking for `\anchor`, thank you ! :D Feel free to write an answer :)

Comment: The exact syntax I needed was : `\ref MyClassSpecialization2 "class bar<int, E>"` after having added an anchor @MyClassSpecialization2 in the documentation of the class specialzation 2 :) Works great thanks @albert !